# Dynamic Form Widget interaction in python tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to generate a blank GUI, with 1 menu Item.

I then use a function to generate a label, a button and an entry widget on the same form when the selection is made from the menu item.

However when I try to use the get() method to get the value of the input in the generated textbox, I get an error. I may have missed some core concept here and this may not be possible, but I would like to know. Following is my code,

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, Entry, Menu

def btn_clientadd():
    print(txt1.get())

def addclient():
    lbl1 = Label(window, text="Client Name :")
    lbl1.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=7,pady=7,sticky='e')

    txt1 = Entry(window)
    txt1.grid(row=1, column=2)
    txt1.focus()

    btn = Button(window, text="Add Client", command=btn_clientadd)
    btn.grid(row=2,column=2,padx=7,pady=7)

window = Tk()
window.geometry('400x200')

menu = Menu(window)
new_item1 = Menu(menu)

menu.add_cascade(label='ClientMaster', menu=new_item1)
new_item1.add_command(label='Add New Client', command=addclient)

window.config(menu=menu)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is because `txt1` is a local variable which is visible only inside  `addclient()`.

Comment: Please include the error in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entry `txt1` is created inside a function and the reference to it is garbage collected when the function ends. One way you can get around this it to declare a `StringVar()` in the global scope and then associate it to the entry.

Examine the example below:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, Entry, Menu, StringVar

def btn_clientadd():
    print(client_string.get()) # Get contents of StringVar

def addclient():
    lbl1 = Label(window, text="Client Name :")
    lbl1.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=7,pady=7,sticky='e')

    # Create entry and associate it with a textvariable
    txt1 = Entry(window, textvariable=client_string)
    txt1.grid(row=1, column=2)
    txt1.focus()

    btn = Button(window, text="Add Client", command=btn_clientadd)
    btn.grid(row=2,column=2,padx=7,pady=7)

window = Tk()
window.geometry('400x200')

menu = Menu(window)
new_item1 = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label='ClientMaster', menu=new_item1)
new_item1.add_command(label='Add New Client', command=addclient)
window.config(menu=menu)

client_string = StringVar() # StringVar to associate with entry

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you @figbeam, I tried to do a return on the function but it wasnt helping, your explanation is perfect.